# Basic python, pass by reference confusion

Tags: python

I am not understanding the difference between these two methods can someone explain? Why in one of them the reference object was changed but in the second one the reference remains unchanged? I come from Java, C# background if that helps. To me it seems like the reference should update in both of them. Thanks

```
def changeme( mylist ):
   "This changes a passed list into this function"
   mylist.append([1,2,3,4]);
   print "Values inside the function: ", mylist
   return

# Now you can call changeme function
mylist = [10,20,30];
changeme( mylist );
print "Values outside the function: ", mylist
```

Values inside the function:  [10, 20, 30, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
Values outside the function:  [10, 20, 30, [1, 2, 3, 4]]

```
def changeme( mylist ):
    "This changes a passed list into this function"
   mylist = [1,2,3,4]; # This would assig new reference in mylist
   print "Values inside the function: ", mylist
   return

# Now you can call changeme function
mylist = [10,20,30];
changeme( mylist );
print "Values outside the function: ", mylist
```

Values inside the function:  [1, 2, 3, 4]
Values outside the function:  [10, 20, 30]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/986145/6486738

Comment: This works exactly the same in Java... **Neither Python nor Java support call by reference**, so assigning to a parameter in will not have an effect in the caller in either language. I can't comment on C#

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the most important things you will learn about Python (well, it was for me).

> Every object is inherently unnamed but you can bind a variable name to it.

When you do:

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
```

two things happen:

- the `[1, 2, 3]` *object* is created; and
- the `x` name is *bound* to it.

That's why, when you change an object, all bound names seem to change<sup>(1)</sup>:

```
>>> x = [1, 2, 3] ; y = x ; x ; y
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
>>> x.append(42) ; x ; y
[1, 2, 3, 42]
[1, 2, 3, 42]
```

You're not changing `x` or `y` in that case, you're changing the object *behind* those variables and, since both variables are bound to that object, both will be affected.

So, how does that affect your question. When you pass a variable to a function, the name in the function definition is simply bound to the same object as the one you passed in:

```
def modList(x):      # 'x' and 'actual' now point to the SAME object.
    x.append(42)     # this will modify that object, no binding changes.
    x = [4, 5, 6]    # this will create NEW object and rebind 'x' to it.

actual = [1, 2, 3]   # object is [1, 2, 3], 'actual' is bound to it.
modList(actual)      # pass object reference to function.
```

So statements that change the *object* (like the first line of `modList`) will change it for all bindings whereas statements that *rebind* (like the second line) will lose access to the original object.

If you want to *change* the object with an assignment-looking statement, you can use array slicing to do so. This works because you're changing the *elements* in the object rather than rebinding `x` to a new object:

```
x[:] = [4, 5, 6]
```

---

<sup>(1)</sup> Note that you can't always change the object behind a binding. Specifically, some things (like strings) are immutable so, if you "change" a string, you actually get a *new* string, distinct from the first:

```py
x = "pax"         # New object, bind x to it.
y = x             # Bind y to that same object.
x = x + "diablo"  # New object, bind x to it. Bindings x and y
                  #   do not affect each other, they are bound
                  #   to different objects.
```

Comment: thank you this is very helpful, makes sense to me now

Answer (score 1):

`mylist = [1,2,3,4]` in the function changes the value of the parameter `mylist`, which is a *copy* of the reference to `mylist` outside of the function. The original reference does not change.

If you want to modify the list (rather than a reference to it), use `mylist[:] = [1,2,3,4]`.